# F# Deedle save Frame to MySql database

Tags: f#, deedle

Python Pandas has a nice "to_sql" function ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)), I tried to find one for F# Deedle but cannot find any. Since I'm not familiar with MySql, writing a function to insert data from Frame is difficult for me.

Wonder if any package that provides similar "to_sql" function as Pandas. Thanks

Comment: I doubt there is. You might be able to make something, which combines the [`SaveCsv`](https://fslab.org/Deedle/frame.html#Loading-and-saving-CSV-files) function and a MySQL bulk insert?

Comment: So far Deedle hasn't any built-in features to write to SQL directly. Unfortunately I do not have time to write another extension yet. If you figure out a solution, any code snippets as issue or pull requests are welcome in the repo.